# Android Chronometer - One second "ticks" late

Tags: android, chronometer

The app is a sports timer for cycling, skiing etc, where racers start at regular intervals. e.g. 1 minute.

In my implementation of OnChronometerTickListener I notice that the calls occur at intervals significantly longer than 1000 mS. I use the elapsed time (between the Tick and the Chronometer's base) to count down the last 5 seconds for each interval. Due to the late callback, I can get ticks at, say, 
    55,500 
    56,600
    57,750
    58,870
    59,980
    61,110

I can therefor skip a whole second when I use m_Elapsed % 1000.
I have even seen the text in the Chronometer get behind and have to skip a second.
I have no problem with accuracy when I do calculations based on the Chronometer's base time and current system time.

Do I have to write my own Chronometer using finer callbacks?
Or is there some other fix?

Comment: chronometer sends messages delayed with 1000 ms hence you see such behavior, you could use own class that uses Handler that posts with finer delay

Comment: Should have said "racers" not r"races".

Comment: I see now that Chronometer does not do the equivalent of "scheduleAtFixedRate". I worked around by using Timer's scheduleAtFixedRate() and a TimerTask. For this I also had to learn how to use a Handler (as pskink suggested) because the TimerTask runs in a thread separate from my GUI / Activity.
Now the Chronometer and my count down can drift apart. I may abandon the Chronometer and use my same "tacks" for both. It's only the on screen display. Any race results I capture are accurate.

Comment: @BryanT Have you found solution to this issue ? I am facing the same issue now.